# Finding the most frequent/common element in a collection?

Tags: list, scala

What is the best way to find the most frequent/common element in a collection? For example:

```
list = List(1, 3, 4, 4, 2)
list.mostCommon   // => 4        !! This is what I want !!
```

Hmm.. What one could do is to do a `groupBy` first and then `map` them by `length`, and then select the biggest one. So then you would get:

```
Map(1 -> List(1), 4 -> List(4, 4), 3 -> List(3), 2 -> List(2))
(...)
Map(1 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 2 -> 1)  // mapped by length. 4 -> 2  since there's two 4s
```

And then in the end, choose the key (`4`) that maps to the highest number (`2`). (*nested question:* what is the best way to do that?). But that seems like a lot of work for such a simple operation..?

Is there a better / more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: nested answer: use `maxBy`.

Comment: Remember there might be more than one value that is the maximum, in which case you can filter your map by the max value found.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have to say that:

```
list.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).maxBy(_._2)._1
```

Or just:

```
list.groupBy(identity).maxBy(_._2.size)._1
```

Doesn't really seem like that much work to me.

If you're worried about the overhead of building up the lists for each value when you only need counts, you could do the following:

```
list.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, Int].withDefaultValue(0)) {
  case (m, v) => m.updated(v, m(v) + 1)
}.maxBy(_._2)._1
```

Or even keep track of the maximum as you go, to avoid the extra traversal at the end:

```
list.foldLeft(
  Map.empty[Int, Int].withDefaultValue(0), -1 -> Double.NegativeInfinity
) {
  case ((m, (maxV, maxCount)), v) =>
    val count = m(v) + 1
    if (count > maxCount) (m.updated(v, count), v -> count)
    else (m.updated(v, count), maxV -> maxCount)
}._2._1
```

This is obviously much less readable than the one-liners above, though, so I'd recommend sticking with them unless you can show (i.e., with benchmarking, not speculation) that they're a bottleneck in your application.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in `Scala 2.13`, we can use:

- [`List::groupMapReduce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMapReduce%5BK,B%5D(key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map%5BK,B%5D) which is (as its name suggests) an equivalent of a `groupBy` followed by `mapValues` and a reduce step.
- [`Map::maxByOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#maxByOption%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB)(implicitcmp:scala.math.Ordering%5BB%5D):Option%5BA%5D) instead of a simple `maxBy` to also handle empty lists:

```scala
List(1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3)
  .groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_+_).maxByOption(_._2).map(_._1)
// Option[Int] = Some(4)
```

This:

- `group`s items (group part of **group**MapReduce)
- `map`s each grouped value occurrence to 1 (map part of group**Map**Reduce)
- `reduce`s values within a group of values (`_ + _`) by summing them (reduce part of groupMap**Reduce**).
- finally gets the optional maximum by nbr of occurrences and map it to get the corresponding item.

---

If you know your list is not empty, then a simple `maxBy` also works:

```
List(1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3).groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_+_).maxBy(_._2)._1
// 4
```

---

The `groupMapReduce` part is an equivalent version [performed in one pass](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L604) through the sequence of:

```
List(1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.map(_ => 1).reduce(_+_))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is really any nicer, but you could do this:

```
List(1, 3, 4, 4, 2).groupBy(identity).maxBy(_._2.size)._1
```

Not the nicest solution. What you want is some way to use maxBy on the list and then reference the list like so:

```
val someList = List(1, 3, 4, 4, 2)
someList.maxBy(x => list.count(_ == x))
```

Comment: I'm an advocate for choosing readability over small performance gains in most cases, but I'm not sure a quadratic solution for a subquadratic problem is ever a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

No, I think that's the best way. But it's not a lot of work...

```
list.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
```

gives you

```
Map(2 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 1 -> 2, 3 -> 1)
```

then, for instance, you can take its `.maxBy(_._2)` (EDITED: thanks @Travis Brown!) and get a tuple `(4,2)` (the number that occurs the most times and how many times it occurs)

If you're a fan of one-liners:

```
scala> List(1, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).maxBy(_._2)
res0: (Int, Int) = (4,2)
```

Comment: Your one-liner only works here because `4` also happens to be the largest value. You need `maxBy` (see my answer).

Comment: The one-liner you provide shows the flaw to this approach. 1 and 4 are both the most frequent values, but only 4 is given.

Answer (score 0):

another variant:

```
val x = List(1, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5)
 x.distinct.foldLeft((0,0))((a, b) => {
     val cnt = x.count(_ == b);
   if (cnt > a._1) (cnt, b) else a
 })._2
```