# Most common string in list with counter

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a function that

*takes a List read from a file as input*

*outputs the most frequently used string as well an integer that shows the number of times that it was used.*

example output:

("Cat",5)

function signature:

```
def mostFreq(info: List[List[String]]): (String, Int) =
```

First,I thought about creating a

- Map variable and a counter variable
- iterating over my list to fill the map
- then iterate over the map

However, there must be a simpler way to do this scala but I'm not used to scala's library just yet.

I have seen this as one way to do it that uses only integers.

[Finding the most frequent/common element in a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878104/finding-the-most-frequent-common-element-in-a-collection)

But I was wondering how it could be done using string and integers.

Comment: I'm not clear on why your signature is `def mostFreq(info: List[List[String]]): (String, Int)` and not `def mostFreq(info: List[String]): (String, Int)`. And why can't you use the solution from the linked post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from the linked post has just about everything you need for this.

```
def mostFreq(info: List[List[String]]): (String, Int) = 
  info.flatten.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).maxBy(_._2)
```

It doesn't handle ties terribly well, but you haven't stated how ties should be handled.